# Getting selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: while trying to click element via Link Text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element By.Link test and getting the below error

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

My Code:

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)
el=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Completed"))).click()
```

[Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVtJ2.png) I am trying to Click (Completed)

Comment: HTML

"<div class="export-section width-custom"><ul class="export-subheader">
<li class="">Completed</li>"

Answer (score 1):

The Element you will try to click isn't a link.
the following line need to be changed

```
el=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Completed"))).click()
```

try to locate it with another option like xpath:
a complete liste can be found here [Selenium-Webdriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

a possible solution could be:

```
el=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, //ul//li[text()='Completed']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul//li[text()='Completed']")))

element.click();
```